# Elegant proof for nonsingular upper triangular matrix has an upper triangular inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am looking for (an elegant proof or a proof that does not use so many results) that a nonsingular upper triangular matrix $A$ has an upper triangular inverse. Here is what I have:

Nonsingular $\iff \det(A) \neq 0 \iff$ the rows of $A$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$

This is where my proof is "awkward/not-elegant/I'm not so sure what to do": From here we can just apply the reduced-row-reduction algorithm. And we will get $I$ the identity matrix. Thus $A^{-1}$ is the product of elementary matrices multiplied by $A$.\

1. I guess a good proof would show that we will indeed get the identity matrix.

Comment: Is this a particular matrix, or an arbitrary one? That's not the case for all non-singular matrices.

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}$$ If the inverse of $A$ is upper triangular, $A$ must be too.

Comment: Really I don't well understand the question, the inverse of nonsingular matrix is unique so why this inverse would be necessary upper triangular?

Comment: I actually read the question incorrectly, I edited my post. Please only give hints, I will probably be able to figure it out now that I have the question right.

Comment: Hint: For each column of the inverse but the last, the product with the last row of $A$ must be $0$. What can you deduce about the column from that?

Comment: I can only deduce that the last row of $A^{-1}$ is all zeros except for the last entry which is $\frac{1}{a_{nn}}$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

We have
$$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det A}\mathrm{Adj}(A)$$
Do you know how we calculate the adjugate of $A$?

**Added: Another proof:** Let $T_n$ denote the vector  space of $n$ by $n$ upper triangular matrices and define the linear transformation:
$$f_A: T_n\rightarrow T_n,\quad M\mapsto AM$$
so $f_A$ is well defined since the product of two upper triangular matrices is upper triangular and if $M\in\ker f_A$ then $f_A(M)=AM=0$ so $A^{-1}AM=M=0$ and then $f_A$ is injective so it's also bijective (*since $T_n$ is a finite dimensional vector space*).

Now since $I_n\in T_n$ then there's a unique matrix $X\in T_n$ such that $f_A(X)=AX=I_n$ so $X=A^{-1}$ is an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: Never heard of the adjugate. I am looking for something that uses only the basics. I get where you are going though. $\det(A)$ is the product of the main diagonal.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u$ be an inversible endomorphism of some vector space $E$. For every subspace $F \subset E$, it is clear that $F$ is stable by $u$ if, and only if, it is stable by $u^{-1}$. Apply this with the family of subspaces $F_i = \mathrm{span}\,(e_1,\dots,e_i)$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ and the canonical endomorphism of $\Bbb R^n$ induced by $A$.